# Geocoder returns wrong result (ie: postal_code), some of the time

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my first post here so please forgive any misunderstandings.
I'm using the google places API (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language=en) and it works good most of the time.

How ever, for certain addresses, it returns the wrong postal_code or neighborhood.

For example, this search query: 
"**St Giles London - A St Giles Hotel, Bedford Avenue, London, United Kingdom**"

Some of the time, it returns postal_code of "WC2E 9HA" (which is wrong), while other times it returns "WC1B" (which is good). This behavior switches periodically. I think that it depends on the server that handles my request.

Can you please help direct me to a solution?

This is my sample code:

```
var postal = "";
var address = "St Giles London - A St Giles Hotel, Bedford Avenue, London, United Kingdom";
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address  }, function (result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (result == null) {
            alert('null');
        } else {
            var address_components = result[0].address_components;
            for (var i = 0; i < address_components.length; i++) {
                if (address_components[i].types[0] == "postal_code") {
                    postal = address_components[i].long_name;
                    console.log(postal);
                }
            }

            alert(postal);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert('status=' + status);
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: If it's a problem with Google's data not being consistent across their servers, I'm not sure there's much you could do about it.  However if you know it's only certain locations, you could store those yourself as exceptions. Check if the address is one of those, and if so use the stored postcode instead of relying on Google.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my code handles different scenarios and random addresses, so I can't store anything. A client found this bug, so I have two options: cheat and handle that address, or find out if it's a real problem that might effect other addresses as well.. I was hoping for someone at google to see if it's a real problem or I'm just imagining things :)

Comment: Report it here https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20API%20v3%20-%20Bug

Comment: Also, you're sticking to the first  result ( results [0]). Perhaps the right answer doesn't always come in that position

Comment: @amenadiel I checked but there only 1 object in that array. I finally went with duncan's idea and "cheated" a bit..